# Send invitation in linkedIn using user "id" only

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api, social-networking

```
{
  "recipients": {
    "values": [
    {
      "person": {
        "_path": "/people/12345",
       }
    }]
  },
  "subject": "Invitation to connect.",
  "body": "Say yes!",
  "item-content":{
       "invitation-request":{
           "connect-type":"friend",
           "authorization":{
              "name":"NAME_SEARCH", //Want to send authorization token
              "value":"pXCC"}
           }
       }
    }
```

I refer [this](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/invitation-api) link here they explain above parameters to send. How can I get the authorization name and the token.

```
**@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=OtheruserId"**
```

and get the response..

```
{
  "firstName": "First name",
  "headline": "Project manager at telecom",
  "lastName": "Lastname",
  "siteStandardProfileRequest": {"url": "http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=285045271&authType=name&authToken=ya_D&trk=api*a3651131*s3722511*"}
}
```

from this response I get the **id** and the **authToken** but I didn't get the authName how can I get that. Please help me to fix and show me a right path..

Comment: Instead of copying the code and expect it to work, you really should read complete article. It has a section `Fields for the XML Body` that explains the purpose of each field, including `authorization `, `name` and `value`.

Comment: @A-Live: how can I get the authorization name and token?

Comment: I think these are values of the response where you got the person details from.

Comment: @A-Live: It not getting we need to get the firstname and lastname then send the details in people search after that only we will get this. But now I struck wit people search it shows 401 unauthorized error

Comment: Look, the article says directly what you need to do: "You can get these authorization codes from standard profile and search results." Read the `Authorization Headers` section.